# Displaying static hyperlink in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am getting the data from the SQL DB from the column name Nature, Hyper link should be decided based on the value of Nature.

If the value of nature is

1. A or B or C : Link should be "http://www.this.is.test1"
2. X or Y or Z : Link should be "http://www.this.is.test2"
3. P or Q or R : Link should be "http://www.this.is.test3"

Output on the page should be :

> Nature Link(Column name on page)

If value is A   ----->     A          (When Clicked on 'A' link http://www.this.is.test1 should open )

If value is Q   ----->     Q          (When Clicked on 'Q' link http://www.this.is.test3 should open )

I am not able to display the Value (A,B,C,P,Q....) and associated link for that.

Tried

1.
Using HyperlinkField in Gridview

```
<asp:HyperlinkField HeaderText="Nature Link" DataTextField="Nature"
    Visible="true" SortExpression="Nature"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.this.is.{0}"
    DataNavigateUrlFields="Nature" target="_blank"></asp:HyperlinkField>
```

Code :

```
protected void dginvoicereport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        var t_nature= Int32.Parse(e.Row.Cells[25].Text.Replace("&nbsp;",""));
        if ((t_nature== 'A') || (t_nature== 'B') || (t_nature== 'C'))
            e.Row.Cells[25].Text = "test1";
        else if ((t_nature== 'X') || (t_nature== 'Y') || (t_nature== 'Z'))
            e.Row.Cells[25].Text = "test2";
    }
}
```

2.
This:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="nature" HeaderText="Nature Link"
    HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a target='_blank'
    href='http://www.this.is.{0}'>Link</a>" />    `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create method in code behind to check he value of Nature and return required link as below

```
protected string GeNatureLink(string nature)
{
    string naturetLink = "http://www.this.is.test1";

    switch (nature)
    {
        case "A": case "B": case "C":
            break;
        case "X": case "Y": case "Z":
            naturetLink = "http://www.this.is.test2";
            break;
        case "P": case "Q": case "R":
            naturetLink = "http://www.this.is.test3";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return naturetLink;
}
```

In `GridView` add below `TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="hyperlink" NavigateUrl='<%# GeNatureLink(Eval("Title") as string) %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hi Wael Abbas,Thanks for the reply. It is working as expected, But I just need one thing to be added. In TemplateField  Text='Link'  , I need actual value to be displayed like A, B , C P ....

Comment: Just replace `'Link'` with `'<%# Eval("Title") %>'`

Comment: Hi Wael Abbas, How can I display specific value as without Hyperlink.

Comment: @bHaRaThN Just use `<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Title") %></ItemTemplate>` or use `<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Literal>`

Comment: I am able to display value which will just look as a Hyperlink , But without any link. But I need to display certain value as a Hyperlink and certain as Text.

Comment: @bHaRaThN did you set `NavigateUrl` property?

Comment: This is what I am using <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="status" NavigateUrl='<%# stauslink_RowDataBound(Eval("status") as string) %>' Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' runat="server" />

Comment: @bHaRaThN I will reply to you question with example